# Why does one computer throw an error and another not, same code?

Tags: r, error-handling

I have a report that I "flatten" because it comes out of the reporting interface rather kludgy.  Something like this, repeating for every employee in the call center:

```
df <- data.frame(Date = c(NA, 2017, 2018, 2019, 2020), AH = c(NA, 1,2,3,4), NAH = c(NA,5,6,7,8), TH = c(NA,9,10,11,12))
df[1,3] <- "Supervisor: Malcolm Reynolds"
df[1,1] <- "Employee: Jane Cobb"
```

I have code to remove the Emp name and Super name from the row they are in, and add them to new columns I created earlier by entering the Emp name in each row for that person. Like this:

```
l <- grep("Employee:", adh$Date) ##find emp/super rows
m <- l[-1] ##new list without first row
m <- append(m,nrow(adh)) ##add last row to new list

##fill in new columns, column 8 is EmpName, 9 is SuperName

for (i in 1:length(l)) {
    adh[as.integer(l[i]):as.integer(m[i]),8] <- adh[as.integer(l[i]),1]
    adh[as.integer(l[i]):as.integer(m[i]),9] <- adh[as.integer(l[i]),3]
    }
```

On my machine, everything works fine, it's all base package code.  My employee runs this, and on the first line inside the for loop, it throws this error:

Error: Assigned data `adh[as.integer(l[i]), 1]` must be compatible with existing data.
i Error occurred for column `Emp_Name`.
x Can't convert  to .

He just installed R and RStudio, I have a ton of other packages installed. I have no idea why this is happening for him and not me.  Note, I'm not an under the hood user.

Comment: Are both machines running the same version of R.  Most likely one is running Version 3.x.x and the other is running 4.0.x

Comment: How did you import the data on each of these machines? Are you both running the exact same version of R? It seems worrisome that you are trying to mix both numeric and character values in the same column.

Comment: To MrFlick: I used readxl to import the data. We pull reports from a front end reporting application in our WFM software.  I flatten it to get it into our data warehouse.  The report is exported in excel and is formatted to look interesting, I guess, or be unusable for easy manipulation.  The second set of code removes the name from the same column as numerics and puts it in its own. I think Dave2e is onto it.